# Multiple shopping carts in one sessions per user with Undercart marketplace

Tags: ubercart

We have a marketplace with multiple vendors offering their products for sales. The specific business model for these people requires the website to offer a seemingly continuous and seamless "add to cart" experience from the user's perspective but at the same time shows separate carts for each vendor the user is buying from and then issues separate invoices for both the users those vendors (each vendor is treated totally independent of the others).

We tried our best to implement it using a single cart but it seems rather unfit to do so. I thought in reality multiple buying sessions are run so we need a system which automatically creates separate carts (per each vendor the user is now buying from).

Ideas ?

I'm on Druapl 6